# Creating a JMS provider in Eclipse to send/receive JMS messages

Tags: java, eclipse, jms, message

I am trying to create a sample JMS application using Eclipse IDE.

I have managed to create a Producer.java and a Consumer.java class to send the messages from the Producer to the Consumer. The Consumer receives the message and prints out the message.

What should I do next to actually send and recieve the messages. I know it has got something to do with creating a JMS Provider, but it would be really helpful if someone could guide me on how to go about it?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Send it over Network, or should a JMS be send by an internal process or via File triggers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you need JMS Provider implementation, i can recommend HornetQ as fast, popular and well-documented.

http://java.dzone.com/articles/hornetq-getting-started

http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.2.Final/quickstart-guide/en/html_single/index.html

http://hornetq.blogspot.com/2009/09/hornetq-simple-example-using-maven.html

good articles to quick start with HornetQ.

or http://activemq.apache.org/getting-started.html, if you preffered ActiveMQ

Answer (score 0):

Yes I suggest also to use HornetQ

with two line of code you could embed an entire jms server into your applications

if you want you could check the new HornetQ book

[www.amazon.com/dp/1849518408/?tag=packtpubli-20](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849518408)